# 1 hour difference between Mariadb timestamp and Django DateTimeField

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, mariadb, backend

I have a simple Django project that uses an existing mariadb database running at localhost as the default database. In the database timestamps are stored correctly, in Django however they are one hour later.

I created a simple database called test with a table called time:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE TABLE time (time_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, time TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO time (time) VALUES (NOW());
```

Then I started a Django project called testproject with an app called testapp. I set the database settings and defined the following model:

```py
class Time(models.Model):
    time_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'time'
```

After running `migrate`, when I open `python manage.py dbshell`, I get:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(`time`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') AS 'utc_datetime' FROM time;
+---------------------+
| utc_datetime        |
+---------------------+
| 2023-12-27 20:40:46 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

which ist correct.
However when I do the same thing with `python manage.py shell`, I get:

```py
>>> from testapp.models import Time
>>> Time.objects.latest('time').time
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 27, 21, 40, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

I noticed this in a more complex project but was able to reproduce it in this very simple example. I live in the timezone CET, in the settings.py folder of the Django project I have `USE_TZ = True` an `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`. However changing neither of them makes a difference. I am using Django version 5.0, mysqlclient version 2.2.1 and MariaDB version 11.1.3. I would really appreciate it if someone could show me a solution to this problem.

Comment: from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    utc = pytz.UTC
    print(utc.localize(datetime.now()))
what does that print?

Comment: Please provide output from `show variables like '%zone';`.

Comment: @RickJames `| system_time_zone | CET    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |`

Comment: @Alvar that simply prints the current time in utc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Django project I have USE_TZ = True an TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

> | system_time_zone | CET    | | time_zone        | SYSTEM |

As I read it, Django is using UTC, but MySQL is using CET.  They differ by 1 hour.

Comment: How do I change the timezone used by MySQL?

Comment: Figured it out with `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';`